# Sending Tracking data to Salesforce CRM

Tags: marketing-cloud

I want to create a Report on Tracking Data (open rate, click rate, deliverability rate) from MarketingCloud into Salesforce CRM Sales/Service Cloud. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Watch the documentation about dataviews https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5 (you need to enable this by support)

Comment: Are you using Marketing Cloud Connect?

Comment: yes I am using Marketing Cloud Connect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using Marketing Cloud Connect, you already have this kind of data available in Salesforce. Here's how you can access it:

1. You can run a tracking report within Salesforce that shows you all the engagement data from Marketing Cloud. In Salesforce, go to Reports and under 'Select Report Type,' expand the 'Other Reports' Folder and select either 'Individual Email Results with Contact' or 'Individual Email Results with Lead'. Choose the metrics that you want to see and run the report. Read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334623&type=1&language=en_US&mode=1
2. Navigate to the Email Send tab in Sales or Service Cloud to access a specific Email Send record. This Marketing Cloud Connect feature provides detailed information about each send. It includes related lists with tracking information on individual email results, aggregate link-level details, and support requests that have been opened for the send. Read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_email_send_record.htm&type=5

Comment: The problem is when I'm sending the mails the Email Send Record is not populating. I cannot see any details in salesforce crm.

Comment: In order to get tracking in Sales/Service Cloud, you need to either use Journey Builder with Salesforce Data entry source, or send to Salesforce Campaign or Report, or to a Salesforce Data Extension. You also need to make sure that when you configure a send, you check the option "Send Tracking Results to Sales Cloud"

Comment: I have created one report of contacts in salesforce sales cloud. now I while sending the mail from the marketing cloud I have selected that report as the targeted. the mail was sent successfully but the tracking history is not populated in tracking>>sends in marketing cloud. as well as it is also not populating in the Email Sent/ send Analytics tab in the sales cloud.  can you please help me with that.

Comment: Did you check the option “Send Tracking Results to Sales Cloud” when you sent the email?

Comment: yes I checked that

Comment: In that case, I would open a support ticket

Comment: I sent mail from marekting cloud, now i can se the data in email sent tab in sales cloud. but i am not able to track the data in Send Analytics tab as well as not in the Email Send >> Tracking Info related list.
it is showing me this msg .(Waiting on tracking from the Marketing Cloud...) . is there any specific time to reflect the tracking data in sales cloud.

Comment: yes, it's defined in the Marketing Cloud tab > Configure Marketing Cloud Connect. I believe 90 mins by default

Comment: yes sure..Thanks a lot for the help.